Angular 18: remove leading e trailing and place as complete field
Using the latest version of Angular (18.2), I am unable to style the input border, changing the colors and the border radius. I've tried several methods, but none of them work. I can't make the field "complete"—there's always this division between trailing and leading. I've also tried different approaches with --no-label, but nothing works.
mat-label is ok
first
Html:
            <form class="form-group mt-5 d-flex flex-column">
                <mat-label class="label">E-mail</mat-label>
                <mat-form-field appearance = "outline">
                    <input matInput placeholder="Insira seu e-mail">
                </mat-form-field>
                <mat-label class="label">Senha</mat-label>

                <button type="submit" class="ds-button full-width">Entrar</button>
            </form>

style.scss
/* estilos globais */

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Rawline", sans-serif !important;
}

::placeholder {
  font-family: "Rawline", sans-serif !important;

}


mat-label {
  color: var(--color-neutral-dark-up);
  font-size: var(--font-size-md);
  font-weight: var(--font-weight-semibold);
}


.mat-mdc-form-field-infix {
  background-color: rgb(175, 123, 123);
  border-radius: 16px !important;
}

Second
.mat-mdc-notch-piece {
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 12px !important;
}

second
Third way
```
.mdc-notched-outline__leading, .mdc-notched-outline__notch, .mdc-notched-outline__trailing {
  border-radius: var(--rounded-8) !important;
  border-color: blue !important;
}

result:
enter image description here
```
